# ViewPager swipe actions

Tags: android-viewpager

My app has three fragments with the home page shown at app launch. And I have two pages one on the 'left' and the other to the 'right'. So, you can think of my home/launch page being in the middle.

I am unable to accomplish this flow: "page 0 <-> page 1 (launch page) <-> page 2" since `ViewPager` moves only in N, N+1 direction not N, N-1 and then back to N, N+1 direction. At this time, I am not necessarily interested in RTL or LTR implementations for I18N/L10N.

I tried using a negative position in `getItem()` however, that didn't work as expected.

Comment: If this is still relevant, show uns someone code, please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you just want to start on the second page? In that case just call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`.

Comment: Thank you @Zar! That did the trick.

Comment: Np. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` to start on the second page.